# How to convert an mjpeg live video format to h.264 format using ffmpeg without increasing the playback speed

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, mjpeg

I have a live mjpeg video stream that I need to be recorded and play in a browser. I am using FFmpeg to record from the HTTP URL using the below command.

ffmpeg -i http://127.0.0.1:5005/hdmi/vflipped/1 -c:v copy Output.mp4

But the recorded video Output.mp4 is not getting played in any browser. (tried with chrome and firefox)
On a search I just found few suggestions to convert the mjpeg codec to h.264 codec.
So I have converted the mjpeg format to h.264 format to get played in a browser using the below command.

ffmpeg -i http://127.0.0.1:5005/hdmi/vflipped/1 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4

But this increased the speed of the recorded video.

Can anyone suggest any other way to play the recorded video in the browser?

Comment: Show the complete log from the second command.

Comment: Try to add `-r 24` before the output file name. This should force FFmpeg to output at 24 fps: `fmpeg -i http://127.0.0.1:5005/hdmi/vflipped/1 -vcodec libx264 -r 24 output.mp4`